# Retrieve table columns via table names in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

How do i retrieve a list of table columns in the database via table name in Entity Framework Database First?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get the names of the columns in C# code, then it would be something like this:

```
var names = typeof(TableName).GetProperties()
                    .Select(property => property.Name)
                    .ToArray();
```

If you need the columns names in the database via query then something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TableName'
```

Comment: I prefer ToList() instead of ToArray(), but that is a totally valid answer anyways.